# Pandas: why am I seeing integers when my dataframe values are floats?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point, integer

I am populating a Data Frame from an Excel file which contains float numbers:

```
A      B
0.88   48.76
1.00   57.02
0.00   100.00
1.00   0.00
0.00   100.00
```

When I load these values into a Data Frame and ask for `head`, I only get integers on the screen. It makes substantial difference to me if I have `1` instead of `0.915`.

```
In[1]: mydf.head(5)
Out[1]:
    A   B
0   0   48
1   1   57
2   0   100
3   1   0
4   0   100

In[2]: mydf.describe()
Out[2]:
      A             B
count 2000.000000   2000.000000
mean  0.082500      88.415000
std   0.275194      26.210251
min   0.000000      0.000000
25%   0.000000      97.000000
50%   0.000000      100.000000
75%   0.000000      100.000000
max   1.000000      100.000000
```

**Why does this happen and how can I make sure values are loaded properly into the Data Frame?**

Comment: How do you load data to `DataFrame` ?

Comment: Can you include the output of `mydf.describe()` ?

Comment: Do you use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) ?

Comment: @jezrael I do not. I load my values by uploading my data to some lists, which I then load into the Data Frame.

Comment: @CF84 - hmmm, what is reason for it?

Comment: Did you try using **pandas** method : read_csv() ?

Comment: I am not sure, but your `lists` contains `floats`, `ints` or `strings` ?

Comment: The lists contain both floats and integers. Do you think the problem might be here, e.g. before creating the Data Frame?

Comment: It is very weird problem, so I think problem can be with constracting `DataFrame`, so I think the best is add code for creating `lists` and for creating `DataFrame`.

Comment: @CF84, Maybe it has something to do with the settings set prior to using. Like, `display.float_format`. Try something like `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.6f}'.format` and see if you can get it to identify everything as `float` instead with a precision upto 6 decimal places. But normally, it shouldn't behave this way.